# Mail Queue Fatal Error

Tags: linux, centos, email, postfix, email-server

I cannot send or receive any emails from my server. I have checked the mailq and it has over 1100 emails. I have tried to run the following to flush the queue:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -q
```

But I get this error:

```
postqueue: fatal: Cannot flush mail queue - mail system is down
```

The mailq is full of emails from 'root' to 'root'. I have provided the maillog and mailq entries below. Does anyone know what could have happened?

I am running CentOS 5.5.

EDIT

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iRkZaAPP) is a paste of the most recent maillog entries. Also [here](http://pastebin.com/85uDuvWa) is the contents of the mailq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log files, I'd say this is your problem:

```
2011-05-15T16:36:01.835702-07:00 ip-XXX-XX-XX-XX lmtpunix[19520]: verify_user(user.root) failed: Mailbox does not exist
```

Obviously if the mailbox doesn't exist, mail cannot be delivered. You'll have to either create an empty mailbox (with correct permissions and in the right place) or you'll need to put a working alias into /etc/aliases for root, and then re-run sendmail -q.

Comment: @woldgangsz - Thank you. So an email was received for root@mydomain.com?

Comment: @Christopher - please don't get me wrong: you can read English, right? It's all there in your log. And I would have to say that running a public mail server is something that does require a bit of determination and diligence, otherwise you'll soon become a statistic for the spammers.

Comment: This explains why a particular email delivery failed, but doesn't seem adequate to explain the OP's error message.